# (ReactJS) Client side displays a list of searches that match query. Why is my output list one character behind (input lag) the search bar input?

Tags: reactjs, server, client

I'm displaying the information correctly, but for whatever reason the input lags behind the placesList that I'm creating. For instance, if I type in "hello", it displays results for "hell". If I type "taco", it displays results for "tac". How can I solve this input lag?

My "sendfindRequest" function gets called when the query event occurs in the input:

```
<Input placeholder="Search for a Place" onChange={event => props.setQuery(event.target.value)}/>
```

There is a useEffect that sends the request on query change:

```
useEffect(() => {
      sendFindRequest(context);
  }, [query]);
```

The request itself:

```
async function sendFindRequest(context) {
  const {findResponse, setFindResponse, query, setPlaces, setListOpen} = context;
  
  if(query.length == 0){/*Do Nothing*/}
  else{
    setFindResponse(await sendAPIRequest({
      "requestType": "find",
      "match" : query,
      "limit" : 100
    }, getOriginalServerUrl()));
  setPlaces(findResponse.places);
  setListOpen(true);
  }
}
```

And then the list is called in the modal like so:

```
<PlaceTable places={props.places} />
```

Which implements these functions:

```
function PlaceTable(props) {
const placeList = props.places ? props.places.filter((place, index) => index < 20).map(place => <PlaceRow place={place} />) : <Row>No Results...</Row>

  return (
    <Table>{placeList}</Table>
  );
}

function PlaceRow(props) {
  const name = JSON.stringify(props.place.name);
    const location = latLngToText(placeToLatLng(props.place));
  const city = JSON.stringify(props.place.municipality);
  const region = JSON.stringify(props.place.iso_region);

  return (
        <Row style={{display: 'inline'}}>
      <br/>
      <tab/>
      <Input type="checkbox" /> 
      <tab />
            Name: {name}
      <br/>
      Where: {city}, {region}
      <br/>
      {location}
      <br/>
    </Row>
    );
}
```

Comment: Technically, this seems correct. Can you try putting  value={query} on the input to make it fully controlled. and try placing a log for the value of query on sendFindRequest function just after destructuring values from context.
If there is a discrepency in the value of the log and the value you see on the UI for input, the issue might probably in your Context.

Comment: @MujeebQureshi I've added some console.log commands in the useEffect, and it IS indeed calling the request each time. I also include the query each time. It is the correct query, and it is being called. What is occuring, I think, is that the displayed list isn't updating itself everytime places changes. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Well this is one of those classic situation where you can use debounce. 
I believe if you send lets suppose 10 requests to the server, you cannot determine which request returns the response first. it may be the one you sent last! 
So what will happen is that you will update the React component with latest data, but when a request that you made first returns after... thats going to reupdate the React component with stale data.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I created another useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(findResponse){
    setPlaces(findResponse.places);
    setListOpen(true);
    }
  }, [findResponse]);
```

and in the request I changed the initial request to a const variable like so:

```
async function sendFindRequest(context) {
  const {setFindResponse, query} = context;
  
  if(query.length == 0){/*Do Nothing*/}
  else{
    const request = await sendAPIRequest({
      "requestType": "find",
      "match" : query,
      "limit" : 100
    }, getOriginalServerUrl());

    setFindResponse(request);
  }
}
```